# What is the utility of the 'return this' in Function.prototype definition when used indirectly?

Tags: javascript

There are four cases-

Case 1:

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func){
        this.prototype[name] = func;            
          //return this; 
    };

    Number.method("testMethod",function(){
        //return Math[ this < 0 ? "ceil" : "floor" ](this);
    });

    console.log(typeof (9.3).testMethod()); //outputs undefined
```

Case 2:

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func){
        this.prototype[name] = func;            
          //return this; 
    };

Number.method("testMethod",function(){
    return Math[ this < 0 ? "ceil" : "floor" ](this);
});

console.log(typeof (9.3).testMethod()); //outputs number
```

Case 3:

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func){
        this.prototype[name] = func;            
          return this; 
    };

    Number.method("testMethod",function(){
        //return Math[ this < 0 ? "ceil" : "floor" ](this);
    });

    console.log(typeof (9.3).testMethod()); //also outputs undefined
```

Case 4:

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func){
        this.prototype[name] = func;            
          return this; 
    };

    Number.method("testMethod",function(){
        return Math[ this < 0 ? "ceil" : "floor" ](this);
    });

    console.log(typeof (9.3).testMethod()); //outputs number
```

I am aware that 'return this' will help in chaining on the added `method()`.

In these cases what difference does the presence of `return this` in the `Function.prototype.method` make if I am going to use the methods that I add to Function.prototype using `method()`.

Comment: It allows method chaining.

Comment: for chaining maybe ... so you can do `Number.method('m1', fn1).method('f2', fn2)` etc

Comment: it allows chaining without as well.

Comment: @IshankDubey We're talking about chaining `.method(…).method(…)`, not `.testMethod().testMethod()`.

Comment: so, for this particular case is the return statement in the 'Function.prototype' needed? @Bergi

Comment: @IshankDubey Yes. Or for the one that passion provided in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with `return` :

```
    Function.prototype.method = function(name,func){
        this.prototype[name] = func;
        return this;
    }

    function test(){

    }

    test.method('get',function(){
        console.log('get method');
    }).method('put',function(){
        console.log('put method');
    });
```

It works perfectly , but if you remove `return` statement . It end up with :
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined`

Comment: the 'testMethod()' is having the return so the chaining happens so my question why exactly he has used the return in the 'Function.prototype.method'

Comment: @IshankDubey  In your snippet , return in the 'Function.prototype.method'    has noting to do with what `testMethod` returns . return in the 'Function.prototype.method'    returns  `Number` function so that you can invoke `method` after .

Comment: when I remove the return statement from the 'Function.prototype' and keep it in the 'testMethod' the 'typeof' returns 'number' but when I remove the 'return' statement from the 'testMethod' and keep it in the 'Function.prototype' the 'typeof' returns u'ndefined'.

Comment: @IshankDubey  You have not understood what the return in `Function.prototype` means ,  it returns the function object , and the function object is the one who calls `method` function , have you ever found than the 2nd parameter `func` is not invoked in `method` .